# will s3 mounting on ec2 consume memory/SSD on ec2

Tags: magento, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I have AWS ec2 instance. I have couple of magento websites hosted on ubuntu ec2.

Now they are getting slow so thinking to move media files on s3 with CSS/JS/Other images.

As those files are already consuming memory and very less memory available on ec2, I am thinking that just to mount s3 bucket on ec2 magento directory so that all media and skin related files will be uploaded in s3 bucket and downloaded by cloudfront.

But my fear is, ec2 should not consume double memory for it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

1. Why are you using cloudfront when you have AWS?
2. Cloudfront should be able to pick up the images when they are on your server. Because actually your ec2 instance seems not to handle all the IOPS caused by accessing the images. So you dont need any s3 when you have a CDN. Furthermore, having lots of images on a webserver does not consume any memory, only when magento resizes them. Maybe this is your bottleneck?
3. Actully for your case AWS has created EFS (Elastic File System). This is an EBS which has a NFS integrated. Meaning, you can mount the EFS on your production and "Image" Servers. EFS is fully high available out of the box and resizes its disk space in realtime automatically with your rising amount of images. So you dont need to manage it.

Comment: I really find your first comment "1. Why are you using Cloudfront when have AWS?" difficult to follow.  Cloudfront is one of the AWS product suite and works great with it.  As for point 2. Cloudfront can use s3 as it's origin and point 3. EFS is still not production ready

Answer (score 0):

sorry. I have mistaken cloudfront with cloudflare. Therefore you seem to work correct. So then, whats exactly the issue? Do you mean disk space when talking about "memory"? Sure they are taking a good amount of disk space. You can buy an extension from the marketplace which will work with s3 easily. Did you already took this into consideration?